# Can I cite two different sources before and after the comma in one sentence?

Tags: citations

For example, if I want to write the sentence like this:

> Although researchers have proved [first thing]（name1, XY), [second thing] is also confirmed effective (name2, XY).

Both the first and second thing belongs to the "although" sentence. I do not want them into two separate sentences.

So can I cite in-text like this? I need to follow the APA7.

Comment: Who would stop you? Are you following a specific style guide? If you've seen this done, why do you think you'd be prevented from doing it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to follow the APA7. And my question is all about if the in-text citation like this is acceptable. Because I have never seen the intext citation like this, they are always at the end of a full-sentence like ……（Name，XY）. or Name（XY）…… .  So I don't know if I could put two citations in a complete sentence consisting of two sentences.

Comment: What APA 7 references/resources have you consulted so far?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem other than style and readability. I suggest you try a couple of different ways of saying what you want to say and make a decision.

This is one situation where citations in footnotes has a readability advantage since they disrupt the flow less.

It is also possible that a reviewer will make a suggestion about it no matter what you do. But write it the way you think it should be done.

Note that ending the sentence at the comma and then starting a new sentence with "Furthermore..." is probably just about equivalent to what you want to say.

Comment: Thank you for your help.